# My Nodes have disappeared!

Tags: texturing

After rendering a very short animation (simple turntable) the nodes for the textures have disappeared. The "use nodes" is active in materials but nothing in the texture node editor window, Did I hide them by accident?

Hope you can help.
Blender 2.91

Comment: Press A then Numpad . or Home button to center view

Comment: Thx, that didnt work, there is a nodes button on the tool bar but no nodes available (greyed out). No check box either, but as i said the "use nodes" is active in materials.

Comment: Make sure you are in the Shader editor, not the Texture Node Editor

Comment: YAY! Ty Gorgious! I see them now. Its a bit misleading as "texture Node Editor" is a very specific thing lol. Have a great day, coffee & donuts on the way.

Comment: thanks too Jachym for replying.

Comment: You did solve my query. It's just that in the Editor Type the Nodes do not show up if Texture Node Editor is selected but do show up when Shader Editor is. All is good now.